# Google Sheet Script to delete all unfrozen rows but last

Tags: google-apps-script

I work with a school district and am flat-out awful with any scripting or codes. I'm currently trying to create a script to delete every row except for the final row (since at least one unfrozen row is required), whether it has data or not, which I plan to time to delete daily. This is for a Google Form that I set up for students to check-in, which means Row 1 is frozen for the Form Questions.

The Sheet will automatically create new rows with each response, which is perfect, but since the amount of rows varies as a result of this, I'm extremely lost on how to create a script that can accomplish my goal. Is anyone able to assist with creating a script?

I managed to create a clear all, but all formatting needs to erase as well, which I know is done best with deleting the rows. I had seen this code and tried working around it, but consistently get "Exception: The parameters (number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.deleteRow." @ Untitled.gs:7. Unsure if I'm just overlooking or misunderstanding how to use it.

```
function myfunc101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const nr = 1;//number of rows to leave at the bottom
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr - nr + 1,sh.getLastColumn());
  sh.deleteRow(sr,rg.getNumRows());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

** Deletes row 2 to last row - 1**

```
function deleteRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.deleteRows(2,sh.getLastRow() - 2);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)